# how to compare and replace the values in array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, crossword

I was working on PHP. This is a crossword game. The code for the board is below:

```
$crossword = array(
    array("+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+"),
    array("+", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    array("+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "+", "+"),
    array("+", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    array("-", "-", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    array("+", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    array("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    array("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    array("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"),
    array("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+")
);
$boardLen = count($crossword);
$words = "pakistan;punjab;uae";
echo "<table>";
for ($row = 0; $row < $boardLen; $row++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($col = 0; $col < $boardLen; $col++) {
        echo "<td style = 'padding : 5px'>" . "<bold>" . $crossword[$row][$col] . "</bold>" . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo $words."<br>";
$wordArr = explode(";",$words);
```

Here there is an associative array in which I made a crossword board. The places where *-* is to be replaced by the words which are at first declared in `$words` and then they are converted into array. Now I am not getting the point of how to compare the values of `$wordArr` array with the crossword associative array elements that have *-* and replace them with that word if the length is equal to it. I need guidance on how to compare the values and replace them as I am new to php,

Comment: you are mixing server side with client side functionalities. PHP will display messages on the page only on reload. So you should post the form, evaluate it and in case of errors re-render it with messages. You should consider interpolating client and server with ajax